# Chrome "SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" with simple JSON

Tags: json, jquery

I have a service that is returning the following json object:

```
{"Success":false}
```

I am using jquery's $.ajax to call this service.  Here is the relevant jquery code.

```
$.ajax(
        {
        url:"/Asset/isServiceTagAvailable?serviceTag=" + this.value,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.Success)
            alert("Service Tag not Available");
        },
        dataType: "json"
        });
```

I keep getting a "SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" error in chrome.
Setting the dataType to "text" makes everything work fine (leading me to believe something is wrong w/ my json formatting)

I've run the JSON response through a JSON validator and everything seems to be in order.

I've seen some posts about this being caused by other things, but I've checked for all of them.

Any insight on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One more thing I forgot to mention, the content type in the response header is set to:  application/json; charset=utf-8

Comment: Try using [`.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) instead of `.ajax()`

Comment: I've changed my code to this, and still observing the same behavior/error.

    $.getJSON("/Asset/isServiceTagAvailable?serviceTag=" + this.value,function (data) {
                if (!data.Success)
                alert(data);
            });

Answer (score 0):

Also try this solution. It may help you.

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```